# 36X12X12 LED Cube Hardware requirements?

Tags: arduino, led

Ive been trying to build a 32X12X12 LED cube (something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1YNyQqbiF0 ) and trying to get some animation running on it. I used the Arduino to get a 8X8X8 cube running and i wanted to know:-

1. Is it possible to do the same with the Arduino (considering limited number of ports)?
2. If Yes, what additional hardware would i require? (Like Multiplexers and Shift Registers)
3. Is there a LED Driver or any other open source HW platform i could use to do this, that allows easy programming also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will multiplex your 3 questions into one answer: I recommend the [MA72xx](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/MAX72XXHardware#WiringLedMatrix) to drive your LEDs. You can drive up to 15 of them from your Arduino, which probably will suffice your 32x32x32 needs.

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. Just went through the specs of the MA72xx, i will give it a shot!